# LinkedList reversing

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, reverse

I am trying to figure how this method could work for reversing a linkedlist. But I just don't know what's going on here. I need to know how it switched the pointers to another direction. Thanks for help.

```
void reverse(struct node** head_ref)
{
      Node* prev = NULL;
      Node* current = *head_ref;
      Node* next;
      while (current != NULL)
      {
          next = current->next;
          current->next = prev;
          prev = current;
          current = next;
      }
      *head_ref = prev;
}
```

Comment: Create a small linked list, maybe with 3 elements.  Then call reverse() and single-step through with a debugger, carefully noting everything that happens.

Comment: @MartinJames I was trying to switch the pointers around by using a diagram. But messed up.

Comment: What is the point of reversing a doubly linked list? In fact most things shouldn't be reversed hence c++'s reverse iterators

Answer (score 1):

There's no real need to reverse this list, since it's doubly linked, but here's how this function works...

We start off with a list of elements:

```
list:    [A -> B -> C -> NULL]
current: A
next:    UNINITIALISED
prev:    NULL
```

First, we look at element A. Its 'next' pointer is pointing to B. We take that pointer to B and back it up in a local variable 'next'. Then we take A's 'next' and point it at the current local 'previous', which is currently NULL. We next update the local 'previous' pointer and set it to A, and finally set the local 'current' pointer to A's 'next', which is element B.

```
list:    [A -> NULL], [B -> C -> NULL]
current: B
next:    B
prev:    A
```

Now, we've finished with the first iteration of the loop, so we go back up to the top and follow it through again. We set the local 'next' to B's 'next', which is C. We set B's 'next' to the current local 'previous', which is A. Finally, we update the local 'previous' to be B and update the local 'current' to be C.

```
list:    [B -> A -> NULL], [C -> NULL]
current: C
next:    C
prev:    B
```

The pattern is pretty evident now, so I'll skip the walkthrough...

```
list:    [C -> B -> A -> NULL]
current: NULL
next:    NULL
prev:    C
```

Now, current is NULL, so the boolean expression in the while loop returns false, and we exit the loop. The last thing that happens is that the list's new 'head' pointer is now set to point to the new head, C.